# ¿Cómo aplico mis estilos css por encima de los de Bootstrap? A pesar de hacer el link despues no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo una página sencilla con una API de newsApi. Aplico estilos de bootstrap cuyos archivos están descargado y posteriormente aplico mis propios estilos, pero no veo ningun cambio.Especificamente intento cambiar el flex direction column que da la clase card por el flex direction row que daría la clase article.
En teoría con colocar el link stylesheet de la hoja propia después del de bootstrap ya debería darle preferencia, pero aún asi no funciona.

Código del html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ccss/a.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="news">
        
    </div>
    
</body>
<script src="a.js"></script>

</html>
```

Código del css:

```
.article{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 100px;
}


.article img{
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
}

.article h2{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Código del JavaScript que crea los elementos:

```
let body=document.querySelectorAll("body")[0]
let articleDiv=document.createElement("div")
articleDiv.setAttribute("id","news")
fetch("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=DGT&apiKey=MIAPI(no sé si la deberia ocultar por si acaso sí)")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.articles.forEach(article => {
      let articleItem=document.createElement("div")
      articleItem.setAttribute("class","card article")
      let articleImg=document.createElement("img")
      articleImg.setAttribute("src",article.urlToImage)
      let articleContent=document.createElement("div")
      articleContent.setAttribute("class","articleContent")
      let articleHeader=document.createElement("h2")
      articleHeader.textContent=article.title
      let articleText=document.createElement("p")
      articleText.setAttribute("class","lead")
      articleText.textContent=article.description
      let articleButton=document.createElement("button")
      articleButton.setAttribute("class","btn btn-primary")
      articleButton.textContent="Ver más"
      articleItem.appendChild(articleImg)
        articleContent.appendChild(articleHeader)
        articleContent.appendChild(articleText)
        articleContent.appendChild(articleButton)
      articleItem.appendChild(articleContent)
      articleItem.style.marginTop="5px"
      articleDiv.appendChild(articleItem)
    });
    body.appendChild(articleDiv)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Usa `!important` Ejemplo. `display: flex !important`

Comment: Puedes crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma insertando el código como _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`). De hacerlo, no olvides importar la librería de bootstrap. Y por cierto, está bien que ocultes el API Key :)

Comment: @padaleiana el problema es que empleo 2 css, el propio y el de bootstrap y no sabría como hacerlo ya que solo deja insertar 1 css

Comment: Es que tenés que añadir bootstrap _como librería externa_ (no agregar tu archivo de bootstrap). Para ello tenés que insertar un enlace del CDN (en [la documentación misma](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/) hay un enlace; coloqué la del 4.6 porque no sé qué versión estás utilizando)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que CSS se aplica según la jerarquía de importancia de estilos
-Aquí lo listo de mayor a menor relevancia

- !important
- #id Estilos en linea
- .clases (pseudo clases o atributos)
- `<elementos />` (o psoudoelementos)
- *selector universal

Entonces si quieres forzar a un estilo puedes usar **!important**, pero no es buena práctica abusar de esta opción.

Comment: Claro. Eso se llama [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Eso me comentó un usuario, pero aún no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema no está en el CSS, sino en la forma de importar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ccss/a.css">
```

Presta atención a las rutas, parece que ambas rutas están apuntando a diferentes lugares. Uno es **CSS** y el otro es **CCSS**

Comment: Tendría que haberlo comentado ya que es verdad que puede dar lugar a confusión, las rutas están bien, se llaman así para separar el css del bootstrap del custom css(ccss), el problema ya está solucionado y precisamente era por las rutas aunque no de esa manera. Aún así muchas gracias por responder

Comment: @Redox lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 saludos.